# javascript tasks are running in the middle of the completion of the frame

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, frame

In chrome devtools performance tab, we can see the frames and tasks which are happening inside that each single frame, as per my understanding the tasks are completed during the start of the frame  then frame is painted.

But in the below screenshot, I am seeing some task(timer fired is executing in the frame completion line)

[image]

could anyone explain why this happens

Comment: Looks like a positioning bug in devtools UI. Try reporting it on https://crbug.com if you can provide a reproducible test to them.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes it a bug , already raised https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798755&q=frame&can=4

Answer (score 1):

After discussed with one of the chrome team member, found that this is the bug in the performance dev tool panel, where the tasks and frames are not related in the timeline,

bug detail link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798755&q=frame&can=4